# LINQ to XML selection/update

Tags: linq-to-xml

If I have the following XML, how would I use LINQ to XML blank out the date fields in each video node? I wanted to do it for the purpose of a comparison in a unit test.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<main>
<videos>
    <video>
        <id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</id>
        <title>Video Title</title>
        <videourl>http://sample.com</videourl>
        <thumbnail>http://sample.com</thumbnail>
        <dateCreated>2011-01-12T18:54:56.7318386-05:00</dateCreated>
        <dateModified>2011-02-12T18:54:56.7318386-05:00</dateModified>
        <Numbers>
            <Number>28</Number>
            <Number>78</Number>
        </Numbers>
    </video>
    <video>
        <id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</id>
        <title>Video Title</title>
        <videourl>http://sample.com</videourl>
        <thumbnail>http://sample.com</thumbnail>
        <dateCreated>2011-01-12T18:54:56.7318386-05:00</dateCreated>
        <dateModified>2011-02-12T18:54:56.7318386-05:00</dateModified>
        <Numbers>
            <Number>28</Number>
            <Number>78</Number>
        </Numbers>
    </video>
</videos>
```

Comment: Please format your code again, I can't see XML but plain text only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to clear the contents of the nodes:

```cs
// Load the XML document
XDocument doc = ...;

// Select the date nodes
var query = doc.Descendants()
               .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("date"));

// Clear the contents of each
foreach (var element in query)
{
    element.SetValue(String.Empty);
}

// Optionally write it back
doc.Save(...);
```

Yields:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<main>
  <videos>
    <video>
      <id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</id>
      <title>Video Title</title>
      <videourl>http://sample.com</videourl>
      <thumbnail>http://sample.com</thumbnail>
      <dateCreated></dateCreated>
      <dateModified></dateModified>
      <Numbers>
        <Number>28</Number>
        <Number>78</Number>
      </Numbers>
    </video>
    <video>
      <id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</id>
      <title>Video Title</title>
      <videourl>http://sample.com</videourl>
      <thumbnail>http://sample.com</thumbnail>
      <dateCreated></dateCreated>
      <dateModified></dateModified>
      <Numbers>
        <Number>28</Number>
        <Number>78</Number>
      </Numbers>
    </video>
  </videos>
</main>
```

Unfortunately it will modify all date nodes no matter where they are in your XML.  Personally I'd prefer to use the [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) query in the above if given the option to be very explicit which nodes should be updated. The same can be done using pure [LINQ to XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_XML), but it's not as elegant as this.

```cs
var xpath = "/main/videos/video/*[starts-with(name(.),'date')]";
var query = doc.XPathSelectElements(xpath);
```